# How to gain control over LMP messages in BT stack?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, wireless, bluez, hci

I'm working on a test setup for Bluetooth (classic not BLE). One of the cases I'm studying is when Adaptive Frequency Hopping (AFH) is not functional, i.e. the BT keeps on hoping on the 79 available channels regardless of the present interference if any.
AFH is supposed to be turned off using the command:

```
hciconfig hci0 afhmode 0
```

This command successfully sets the status of AFH mode to "Disabled" when queried by hciconfig but here's where my problem appears: the LMP_set_AFH message that is transmitted during the link setup phase has the AFH_mode PDU set to "enabled" even though I disabled it prior to the link setup start. I need this message to contain AFH_mode PDU "disabled" according to the standard.

My question is the following: Is there any way to gain control over the LMP part of the protocol stack? I believe that the solution to my problem lies there. I'm open for whatever tool, programming language, ... etc that can help me do this.

Comment: how did you checked LMP messages , is it using sniffer or any utility available in ubuntu as hcidump can check only controller/host commands/events

Comment: I have the chance to use a BT air sniffer to check the whole communication flow, baseband upwards ...

Comment: Hope you have used sudo permissions to change afh mode, i don't have FTS to check further, also need to check in spec as during device connect/scan , is it mandatory to have afh mode enabled or not >

Comment: I am also quite interested in this. I am using bluez 4.98; if anyone can point me in the right direction I would be grateful. AFAIK making changes to hci.c do not seem to help